# Kendo ui grid: change field type depending in the row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, kendo-ui

I'm having a issue that I dont know how to afford. I have a kendo grid which is being poblated with a json file.

The issue is that in the json file there is a field that has a different type in different elements.

I'll explain myself with an example:

```
"listaPreguntas": [
    {
        "idPregunta": 1126,
        "idTipificacion": 1712,
        "tipoPregunta": "E",
        "pregunta": "¿DE QUE COLOR ES?",
        "numeroOrden": 2,
        "respuestasPosibles": [
            {
                "idRespuestaPosible": 1066,
                "respuestaPosible": "HOSPITAL"
            },
            {
                "idRespuestaPosible": 1068,
                "respuestaPosible": "AMBULATORIO"
            },
            {
                "idRespuestaPosible": 1070,
                "respuestaPosible": "CENTRO SALUD"
            },
            {
                "idRespuestaPosible": 1072,
                "respuestaPosible": "UNIDAD MOVIL"
            },
            {
                "idRespuestaPosible": 1074,
                "respuestaPosible": "UNIDAD DONACION"
            },
            {
                "idRespuestaPosible": 1076,
                "respuestaPosible": "UNIDAD MOVIL (UVI)"
            }
        ],
        "idTipoEnumerado": 1
    },
    {
        "idPregunta": 1150,
        "idTipificacion": 1712,
        "tipoPregunta": "T",
        "pregunta": "¿cuantas personas?",
        "numeroOrden": 1,
        "respuestasPosibles": null,
        "idTipoEnumerado": 0
    },
    {
        "idPregunta": 1152,
        "idTipificacion": 1712,
        "tipoPregunta": "F",
        "pregunta": "¿Mayores?",
        "numeroOrden": 3,
        "respuestasPosibles": null,
        "idTipoEnumerado": 0
    }
```

You can see three objects in the json file, the first object has a type "E" and has six possible values, the second object has a type "T" (Text) and the last one is a boolean.

What i need is to show in the grid a column which type change depending on the type of the json. I need to have a text value in some cases, a checkbox and a dropdownbox.

I hope you could understand me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example for custom editor from http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.editor

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "name",
    editor: function(container, options) {
     var input = $("<input/>");
     input.attr("name", options.field);
     input.appendTo(container);

     if(options.model.tipoPregunta == 'E')
     {
         input.kendoDropDownList( ... );
     }
     if(options.model.tipoPregunta == 'T')
     {
          ....
     }
     if(options.model.tipoPregunta == 'F')
     {
          ....
     }
    }
  } ],
  editable: true,
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" } ]
});
```

`options.model` is a row dataItem

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a template for your column in your grid config:

```
columns: [{
  field: "respuestasPosibles",
  template: function(e){
    if ( (e.tipoPregunta === 'E') && $.isArray(e.respuestasPosibles) ){
      var st = '';
      $.each(e.respuestasPosibles, function(i, a){
        st += a.respuestaPosible + '(' + a.idRespuestaPosible + ')<br>';
      });
      return st;
    }
    else{
      // The cell will be empty
      return '-';
    }
  }, ....
]
```